# ROR...Retrieve data from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For every `original_url` (entered by user) I generate a `short_url`, and, after saving them into the db, show the `short_url` in place of the `original_url`. I was able to do up to this.

Now I want to see that if an URL has already been shortened, so it can be retrieved from the database directly without shorting again.

My idea of doing this is to compare `original_url` entered by a user to the ones in db, and if found retrieve `short_url` directly, else shorten `original_url`.

But I am unable to do this ... please help me. If there is any other better idea please let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
 def show
    @url = Url.find(params[:id])
    if Url.find_by_original_url(@url.original_url)
      @url.short_url
    else
      @short_url
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're filling the short_url column then why not just check to see if there's something in there?

```
def show
   @url = Url.find(params[:id])
   unless @url.short_url
      # shorten the URL
   end
end
```

or

```
def show
   @url = Url.find(params[:id])
   if @url.short_url
   else
      # shorten the URL
   end
end
```

Comment: That's fine, but how can I check if original_url entered by user is already in db or not...if found how should I retrieve original_url's  short_url.

Comment: Thanks conner for your answer...the reason I don't use unless is I get confused with if and unless....I just feel comfortable with if...

Comment: If you're not comfortable with unless then use the updated answer. It might be better to check if there's already an original_url in the database using form validation. Look into uniqueness.